# How to prove that $T \frac{d^2 T}{d x^2} = T f \frac{df}{dT}$

Tags: derivatives

Considering that:

\begin{equation}
   f(T) = \frac{dT}{dx}
\end{equation}

and:

\begin{equation}
  T \frac{d^2 T}{d x^2} = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  T f \frac{df}{dT} = 0
\end{equation}
how to prove that

\begin{equation}
  T \frac{d^2 T}{d x^2} = T f \frac{df}{dT}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the properties of differentials (assuming we don’t yet know that given expressions are both $0$):$$Tf\frac{df}{dT} = T\cdot \frac{dT}{dx}\cdot\frac{d\left(\frac{dT}{dx}\right)}{dT}=T\cdot \frac{dT}{dx}\frac{\frac{d^2T}{dx}}{dT} = T \cdot \frac{dT}{dT}\cdot\frac{d^2T}{dx dx} = T\frac{d^2T}{dx^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

The claim $T \frac{d^2 T}{d x^2} = T f \frac{df}{dT}$ simply follows from the fact that both sides of the equation are equal to $0$, according to the information you provided.